# OAuth and redirect_uri in offline Python script

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, deviantart-api

I'm currently trying to write a Python script that will use Deviantart's API to automatically shuffle my favourites. To do that I need to first log in in my script. Deviantart uses OAuth2 authentication, which requires a redirect_uri, which as I understand it is supposed to be the server where my application is running.

However I'm running the script locally on my computer (not on a server) and just sending http requests via Python's `Requests` library. How do I then authenticate, when the OAuth procedure sends the code required for the authentication token as a parameter of a `GET` call to the redirect_uri, which points to nowhere in particular for me? Is there no way to authenticate without running a server?

### EDIT

My problem is still that I'm running a simple offline script, and I'm not sure how to authenticate from it.

This is my authentication code so far:

```
import binascii, os, requests

def auth():
    request = 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/authorize'
    state = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(160))
    params = {
        'response_type': 'token',
        'client_id': 1,
        'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:8080',
        'state': state,
        'scope': 'user'
    }
    r = requests.get(request, params)
    print(r)
```

The printed response is simply a 200 HTTP code, rather than an access token (obviously, since the username and password haven't been entered anywhere). The request is sent to DA's authorisation page, but since the page itself doesn't actually open in my script, I can't enter my username and password to log in anywhere. And I can't directly send the username and password in the `GET` request to authenticate that way either (again obviously, since it would be a terrible idea to send the password like that).

Preferably I'd like a way to simply have the user (me) prompted for the username and password in the console that the script is running in and then have the script continue executing after the user has successfully logged in.

Alternatively, if the above is not possible, the script should open the authorisation webpage in a browser, and then continue execution once the user logs in.

How would I go about realising either of these two solutions in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per request, I'm updating this question with the code I ended up using for my script's authentication in the hope that it helps somebody.

```
import webbrowser
import requests
import urllib.parse
import binascii
import os
import time
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

AUTH = 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/authorize'
TOKEN = 'https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token'

code = ''
state = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode('utf-8')


class Communicator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client_id = '<insert-actual-id>'  # You get these two from the DA developer API page
        self.client_secret = '<insert-actual-secret>'  # but it's safer if you store them in a separate file
        self.server, self.port = 'localhost', 8080
        self._redirect_uri = f'http://{self.server}:{self.port}'
        self._last_request_time = 0

    def auth(self, *args):
        scope = ' '.join(args)

        params = {
            'response_type': 'code',
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'redirect_uri': self._redirect_uri,
            'scope': scope,
            'state': state
        }
        request = requests.Request('GET', AUTH, params).prepare()
        request.prepare_url(AUTH, params)
        webbrowser.open(request.url)
        server = HTTPServer((self.server, self.port), RequestHandler)
        server.handle_request()

        params = {
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': self._redirect_uri
        }
        self._get_token(params)

    def _get_token(self, params):
        r = requests.get(TOKEN, params).json()
        self.token = r['access_token']
        self.refresh_token = r['refresh_token']

    def _refresh_token(self):
        params = {
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token': self.refresh_token
        }
        self._get_token(params)

    def _request(self, func, url, params, sleep=5, cooldown=600):
        t = time.time()
        if t - self._last_request_time < sleep:
            time.sleep(sleep - t + self._last_request_time)
        self._last_request_time = t

        max_sleep = 16 * sleep

        params['access_token'] = self.token
        while True:
            try:
                r = func(url, params).json()
                if 'error_code' in r and r['error_code'] == 429:
                    sleep *= 2
                    time.sleep(sleep)
                    if sleep > max_sleep:
                        raise ConnectionError("Request timed out - server is busy.")
                elif 'error' in r and r['error'] == 'user_api_threshold':
                    raise ConnectionError("Too many requests")
                elif 'error' in r and r['error'] == 'invalid_token':
                    print("Refreshing token.")
                    self._refresh_token()
                    params['access_token'] = self.token
                else:
                    return r
            except ConnectionError:
                print(f"Request limit reached - waiting {cooldown // 60} minutes before retrying...")
                time.sleep(cooldown)

    def get(self, url, params):
        return self._request(requests.get, url, params)

    def post(self, url, params):
        return self._request(requests.post, url, params)


class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        global code
        self.close_connection = True
        query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path).query)
        if not query['state'] or query['state'][0] != state:
            raise RuntimeError("state argument missing or invalid")
        code = query['code']


BROWSE = 'browse'
BROWSE_MORE_LIKE_THIS = 'browse.mlt'
COLLECTION = 'collection'
COMMENT = 'comment.post'
FEED = 'feed'
GALLERY = 'gallery'
MESSAGE = 'message'
NOTE = 'note'
PUBLISH = 'publish'
STASH = 'stash'
USER = 'user'
USER_MANAGE = 'user.manage'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    com = Communicator()
    com.auth(BROWSE, COLLECTION)  # request specific permissions
    ...  # do stuff with com.get() and com.post() requests
```

Answer (score 2):

If your application is offline, you cannot use the Authorization Code nor the Implicit grant type: both flows require a redirection URI.

As your python script cannot be reached from the Internet and because Deviantart does not allow the use of another grant type (except Client Credentials, but not relevant in you case), then you won't be able to issue any access token.

Your application must be accessible from the Internet.

Comment: I've updated my registered application to use the implicit grant and fixed my code. However I'm still facing the problem of my authentication running in an offline python script, rather than a website or web application. I've edited my question with my authentication code and a  slightly more detailed description of my problem and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to get authorization token using received code. This token will be used to access DeviantArt afterwards.

Refer to https://www.deviantart.com/developers/authentication (section "Using The Authorization Code Grant").

Comment: But how do I get the code if it's not a part of the response I get to my http request?

Comment: Yes, how would you get the code if it's not part of the response Did you solve this @MatedeVita

Comment: @AdityaRajgor Sorry for the late response. At some point I managed to make my application work and authenticate properly. I've pasted the code it uses into its own answer, and I hope it helps you.